# How to delete a user out of multiple instances of CRM Dynamics?

Tags: dynamics-crm

Need help with deleting a user out of 15 different instances of MS CRM Dynamics. Is there a faster way of doing this rather than deleting the person out one instance at a time?

Comment: These are one off request, so maybe you can write console app if you want to go through multiple connection strings & do a sdk call against each instance.

Comment: What did you end up with?

Comment: I am going to go your route- I like the Console App because I know C# and think it may be easier than learning JS however, these one off scripts are not really what my boss wants. After I finish up a project I am working on, I will have time to work on this a let you know! Thanks for the idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is crm onpremise or online, deleting systemuser is not possible (atleast by supported way) & not recommended to do in unsupported way (like SQL Delete in onpremise).

1. You can remove all the security roles & teams she/he is part of (take care of all WF, records they own)
2. Only you can disable by doing so in onpremise or by revoking license in O365 portal to replicate in crmol
3. If the AD account is removed/disabled it should replicate in Dynamics
4. No way to do in bulk across organizations anyway

Edit:

Based on comments, C# Console application can be developed, to iterate through multiple CRM connection strings & issue a sdk Service call to target system user record in each instance.